# Transforming source columns to create unique destination column in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have been building an SSIS package that transfers data between two databases with different schemas. In the destination database one column has a unique key constraint, and the data needs to be populated from 2 source database columns like:

```
SELECT (LOWER(LEFT(Col1.Column1, 5)) + LOWER(LEFT(Col1.Column2, 5)))
```

i.e. The first 5 characters from each column, plus an incrementing number at the end if there are duplicates.

The incrementing number has to be dependent on the first 10 characters so every different variation has its own incrementing number. Ex:

**Dest.Column**
apapapap1
apapapap2
apapapap3
epepepep1
epepepep2

This package is also run every week, so adding the necessary column to the SSIS OLEDB source won't work.

**So my question is:** Is it possible to carry out this transformation in SSIS before writing to the destination database, and if so, how?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited question for clarification.

Comment: Can you do this in SQL at the source or destination?  Doing this in SSIS seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'd also suggest doing this in the SQL statement that reads from your source.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more it seems you should reconsider this requirement.  There is probably an easier way to accomplish the purpose for this column, unless you really need this specific sequence of information.

Comment: While I don't want to be that person who tells you you're doing things wrong instead of giving you an answer, could you explain *why* you need the unique column to have that particular value in it? I could come up with an answer, but don't want to waste your time and mine if there's a simpler solution which would fit your requirements.

Comment: The databases I work with are used by different softwares. In 'destination' database (the one with UQ) particular rows are identified by UQ column (values are: 5char+5char+runningnumber as stated before). And for why we use UQ column is that the software that uses 'destination' database uses also outside application that won't accept GUID or integer as identifier. As it is source database doesn't have UQ value. According to the comments / answers it would seem that the best way is to generate the UQ-column values after data transfer.

Comment: Yes - if it absolutely has to be that exact format, then that's probably the best way. If the number didn't need to be based on the 10 character combination (i.e. the numeric part of the ID was unique on every row) then it would simplify matters, but I still don't think SSIS would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you could do this in your source SQL statement using `partition by`, something like:

```
select 
    C.Column1 + C.Column2 + 
        case 
            when (select count(1) from Col1 C1 where C1.Column1 = C.Column1 and C1.Column2 = C.Column2) > 1 then 
                cast(row_number() over (partition by C.Column1 + C.Column2 order by C.Column1, C.Column2) as varchar) 
            else 
                '' 
            end
from 
    Col1 C
```

That doesn't include the left(,5) but would be simple to add.  For any identical 10-char combination, it adds a number, so for inputs of

`abcdef`, `ghijkl`
`abcdef`, `ghijkl`
`abcdef`, `ghijkl`
`lmnopq`, `rstuvw`
`xyzabc`, `defghi`
`xyzabc`, `defghi`

...you get:

`abcdefghijkl1
abcdefghijkl2
abcdefghijkl3
lmnopqrstuvw
xyzabcdefghi1
xyzabcdefghi2`

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff39d/1/0).

Comment: I think the problem is that there will be incremental loads, and this would create duplicates if the same 10-character value (apapapap, for instance) were loaded on more than one occasion.

Comment: That's what my query achieves - it adds the number to keep them unique.  I'll add a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if you were selecting the entirety of the source data on every load, though? If you insert abcdefghijkl on the first week, and then on week two you select only the new data and find it also has abcdefghijkl in it, when you insert you will receive a unique key violation error. I *think* that's the issue the OP is trying to explain when saying a modification to the source query won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this using a custom query would be the preferred option here but if you have to do this in SSIS, you could try generating 2 columns in the SSIS, one that appends the two columns from your source (*source1*), and another that contains these combinations from your destination (after removing the number) (*dest1*). You can then configure a lookup block and count the number of entries in the *dest1* column corresponding to each entry in *source1* and appending (this number +1) to the end of *source1*.